# Serialize the array

Tags: jquery

I have called serialize on array

```
inputColl.serialize();
```

How to loop to it and print values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cpharmston and cletus have solid approaches.  I'll offer a plain JavaScript approach and an approach you should not use:

How to loop through an array using plain ol' JavaScript:

```
var arr = inputColl.serialize();
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
  //do something with arr[i];
}
```

Don't confuse the loop above with this one:

```
var arr = inputColl.serialize();
for(var i in arr)
{

}
```

The JavaScript for/in statement loops through an object's properties.  This is a very different operation than looping through an array's contents, but it is a common mistake to make.  This is especially common if you use languages like C# and are expecting behavior similar to its foreach construct.

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.each()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) (not the same as [`jQuery().each()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)) can iterate over nearly any iterable object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(inputColl, function(n, i) {
  alert(n);
});
```